# Where is to get an implementation of window frame stream processing in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, winapi, pywin32, mss

Full question is: «Where is to get a Python implementation of handling the window frame stream of a process ran by subprocess with the CREATE_NO_WINDOW flag in Windows?».
I need a function in this form (pseudocode):

```
def handle_stream(pid, callback):
    while psutil.pid_exists(pid):
       <wait for new frames from window created by process with the PID>
       bitmap = <get bitmap>
       callback(bitmap)
```

To do this, you need to have a lot of experience in WinAPI development, which I don't have. Experts, help!

The idea of using Mss and getting window borders is certainly not appropriate here. There is no solution on the Internet (at least written in Python).

Comment: Please give [ask] a **thorough** read.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have a look at [cpp/ScreenCaptureforHWND](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows.UI.Composition-Win32-Samples/tree/master/cpp/ScreenCaptureforHWND).